# Problems upgrading to SQL Server Express 2008 SP2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

Just this morning, I installed SQL Server 2008 Express SP2 from the Web Platform Installer. When I went to restore some databases, the error message was that my database files are from version 10.5 and I have version 10.0.4000. I tried downloading [this file from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727), but it errored out saying that I don't have anything to upgrade in my machine.

I ran this code:

```
SELECT 
  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version',
  SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Service Pack', 
  SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Edition',
  SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
  SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name'
```

And got back this:

```
10.0.4000.0 SP2 Express Edition SQLEXPRESS  DEV-PC1\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: In the end, I made the assumption that I did not have what I thought I had and manually downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 Express from here and "upgraded" what I had.  It worked. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're fine and patched up to date, just slightly confused on nomenclature. Fantastic job btw on finding and running that query, many folks don't go to that effort.

Despite the similarity in names, SQL Server 2008 (10.00) and SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50) are distinct *versions* of the product SQL Server. The *Edition*, denotes the product license, in your case, Express.

A [Service Pack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_pack), SP, is a collection of [Cumulative Updates](http://skmullen.wordpress.com/2008/09/05/confusion-what-is-a-cumulative-update-vs-an-infrastructure-update-vsa-service-pack/), CU, and usually some minor feature fixes/improvements. To further muddy the waters, a Hot Fix or QFE is a software patch that is focused on fixing a specific issue.

The best list for tying versions to available fixes is this site, [SQL Server Version Database](http://sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx) At this time, you are at the current Service Pack level "2008 + Service Pack 2" as your version number indicates (10.00.4000) There have been 4 Cumulative Updates released since then SP2 and a QFE (which patches an XML vulnerability)